# Error returned after setting element equal to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I was given a guide to create a memory tile game for a Uni project, I've run into a little problem with the program as I'm getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. Specifically for this line here document.getElementById("memory_board").innerHTML = output;

I don't understand why this error is happening as i did set output equal to something so it would not be null.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- style settings-->
        <style>
            div#memory_board
            {
                background:#CCC;
                border:#999 1px solid;
                width:800px;
                height:540px;
                padding:24px;
                margin:0px auto;
            }
            div#memory_board > div
            {
                background: pink;
                border:#000 1px solid;
                width:71px;
                height:71px;
                float:left;
                margin:10px;
                padding:20px;
                font-size:64px;
                cursor:pointer;
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            // global variable declaration

            // TODO declare array "memory_array" that contains 24 items, 12 pairs (e.g. A, A, B, B, etc...)
                var memory_array = new Array("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F", "G", "G",
                "H", "H", "I", "I", "J", "J", "K", "K"," L", "L", "M", "M", "N", "N", "O", "O", "P", "P", "Q", "Q",
                "R", "R", "S", "S", "T", "T", "U", "U", "V", "V", "W", "W", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z");
            // TODO declare array "memory_values" with no data 
                var memory_values = new Array();
            // TODO declare array "memory_tile_ids" with no data 
                var memory_tile_ids = new Array();
            // TODO declare a variable for keeping tracking of how many tiles are flipped 
                var tiles_flipped = 0;
            // TODO add an anonymous function to the Array object called memory_tile_shuffle
            Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function()
            {
                // TODO declare variable "length" set equal to the length of the array
                    var leng = memory_array.length;
                // TODO declare variable "rand"
                    var rand = 0;
                // TODO declare variable "temp"
                    var temp = 0;
                // TODO loop while the value of --length (using predecrement) is greater than 0
                while(--leng < 0)
                {
                    //TODO set variable rand equal to Math.floor(Math.random() * (length + 1))
                        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (leng + 1));
                    // TODO set variable temp equal to this array at index rand
                        temp = memory_array[rand];
                    // TODO set this array index rand equal to this array index length
                        memory_array[rand] = memory_array[leng]
                    // TODO set this array index length equal to temp
                        memory_array[leng] = temp;

                }
            }

            // TODO write function newBoard, no parameters, to reset data for the game
            function newBoard()
            {
                // TODO reset variable for tiles flipped to equal 0
                    tiles_flipped = 0;
                // TODO create a variable for output set equal to an empty string
                    var output = " ";
                // TODO call anonymous function memory_tile_shuffle
                    memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
                // TODO perform a for loop from index 0 to the length of memory_array
                for(var index = 0; index < memory_array.length; index++)
                {
                    // TODO concatenate variable "output" to equal
                    //      '<div id="tile_'
                        output = output.concat('<div id="tile_');
                    //      concatenate the looping variable
                        output = output.concat(index);
                    //      concatenate '" nclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''
                        output = output.concat('"onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\'');
                    //      concatenate memory_array with index of the looping variable
                        output = output.concat(memory_array[index]);
                    //      concatenate '\')"></div>'
                        output = output.concat('\')"></div>');


                }

                // TODO update the document object, element id called 'memory_board', innterHTML
                //      so it is equal to the output variable
                    document.getElementById("memory_board").innerHTML = output;

            }

            // TODO write function memoryFlipTile with parameters tile and val
            function memoryFlipTile(tile, val)
            {
                // TODO check if the innerHTML of object tile is equal to "" and
                //      the length of array memory_values is less than 2
                if(tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2)
                {
                    // style settings for the background of the tile object
                    tile.style.background = '#FFF';

                    // TODO set object tile innerHTML equal to the val parameter
                        tile.innerHTML = val;
                    // TODO check if the length of array memory_values equals 0
                    if(memory_values == 0)
                    {
                        // TODO call function push on array memory_values passing 
                        //       val as an argument
                            memory_values.push(val);

                        // TODO call function push on array memory_tile_ids passing
                        //      tile.id as an argument
                            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);

                    } 
                    // TODO check if the length of array memory_values equals 1
                    else if(memory_values == 1)
                    {
                        // TODO call function push on array memory_values passing 
                        //       val as an argument
                            memory_values.push(val);

                        // TODO call function push on array memory_tile_ids passing
                        //      tile.id as an argument
                            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);

                        // TODO check if memory_values index 0 equals memory_values index 1
                        if(memory_values[0] == memory_values[1])
                        {
                            // TODO update the value of variable tiles_flipped to be increased by 2
                                tiles_flipped = tiles_flipped + 2;
                            // TODO clear array memory_values
                                memory_values.length = 0;
                            // TODO clear array memory_tile_ids
                                memory_tile_ids.length = 0;

                            // TODO check to see if the whole board is cleared by 
                            //      comparing the number of tiles_flipped being equal to
                            //      the length of array memory_array
                            if(tiles_flipped == memory_array.length)
                            {
                                // TODO using an alert dialog box inform the user that
                                //      the board has been cleared and a new board is
                                //      being generated
                                    alert("The board has been cleared and a new board is being generated");

                                // TODO update object document, id 'memory_board', innerHTML
                                //      to be equal to ""
                                    document.getElementById("memory_board").innerHTML = "";

                                // TODO call function newBoard
                                newBoard();

                            }
                        } 
                        // otherwise
                        else 
                        {
                            // TODO write function flip2Back so it flips the turned over tiles to
                            //      no longer be visible
                            function flip2Back()
                            {
                                // Flip the 2 tiles back over
                                // TODO declare variable tile_1 set equal to object document,
                                //      element id memory_tile_ids, index 0
                                    var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);

                                // TODO declare variable tile_1 set equal to object document,
                                //      element id memory_tile_ids, index 1
                                    var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);

                                // style settings for tile_1
                                tile_1.style.background = 'pink';
                                tile_1.innerHTML = "";

                                // style settings for tile_2
                                tile_2.style.background = 'pink';
                                tile_2.innerHTML = "";

                                // TODO clear array memory_values
                                    memory_values.length = 0;

                                // TODO clear array memory_tile_ids 
                                    memory_tile_ids.length = 0;
                            }

                            // TODO call function setTimeout passing arguments function flip2Back
                            //      and the value 700
                                setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- create a div with id attribute equal to "memory_board" -->
            <div id = "memory_board"> </div>

            <!-- in the script tag 
                // TODO call function newBoard-->
            <script> 
                    newBoard();
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<div id = document.getElementById("memory_board") </div>` is not valid HTML. Try `<div id="memory_board"></div>`. When I run the rest of the code I just end up with a gray square. No errors though.

Comment: Thanks, My intended objects did appear on the screen, but in an incorrect why, i think this may be due to some other issues but I'll still award you with the correct answer as you fixed my error.

Comment: Actually ignore that I'm still getting the error

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6fne49r9/ there's still an onclick error, but the tiles render.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be an issue with the onclick, and thee also appears to be a problem with my shuffling function, im rereading my code to see if i can get to the root of the problem